# Condition OR with variables in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, conditional-statements, azure-pipelines

I have three conditions as variables (isMaster, isRelease, isHotfix):

```
variables:
  isMaster: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
  isRelease: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/')]
  isHotfix: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/hotfix/')]
  checkCondition: $[or(variables.isMaster, variables.isRelease)]
```

And the problem is when I take two 'false' for the OR condition (like checkCondition).
I should get 'false' but for some reason I get 'true'.

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
       inputs:
         script: |
           echo %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH%
           echo %ISMASTER%
           echo %ISRELEASE%
           echo %ISHOTFIX%
           echo %CHECKCONDITION%
       condition: or(variables.isMaster ,variables.isRelease)
...
Result:
...
refs/heads/someBranch
False
False
False
True
Finishing: CmdLine
```

Anyone have an idea why the condition gives the wrong result?
Thank You!

Comment: Can you try `condition: or(variables.isRelease ,variables.isMaster)`? It can make difference https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1236160/and-condition-on-stage-level-is-incorrectly-evaulu.html

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej that would be hilarious. I have had similar issues in the past. You can try wrap your or condition in: `and(succeeded(), <your or condition>)`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still incorrect (I'm getting 'true').

Comment: But if I put full conditions in OR $[or(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))], I am getting the correct 'false' :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When use [OR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#or), you need to use `or(expression, expression)`, then it will cast expression to Boolean for evaluation. If you use `or(variables.isMaster ,variables.isRelease)`, there are two characters, no expression to cast to Boolean. You need to use `or(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))` instead.

Answer (score 4):

As previously stated the or needs it to be an expression but if you want it a bit more readable and only have the evaluation of the expression once in your variables section you could do it like this:

**or(eq(variables['isMaster'], 'true'), eq(variables['isRelease'], 'true'))**

Example with a and containing a or with an and statement in it:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Download feed.xml
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: vanillaResourceConnection
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az storage blob download --account-name $(storageAccount) --container-name '$web' --name feed.xml --file .ado\downloadedFeed.xml
   condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['isMaster'], 'true'), and(eq(variables['isTag'], 'true'), eq(variables['releaseCheck.isRelease'], 'true'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that this is possible as it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> Conditions are evaluated to decide whether to start a stage, job, or step. This means that nothing computed at runtime inside that unit of work will be available. For example, if you have a job which sets a variable using a runtime expression using $[ ] syntax, you can't use that variable in your custom condition.

but it can't be used anywhere. So if you have steps on your root level it will not work, but it should if you put this in this way

```yaml
variables:
  isMaster: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
  isRelease: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/')]
  isHotfix: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/hotfix/')]
  checkCondition: $[or(variables.isMaster, variables.isRelease)]

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage A!

- stage: B
  condition:  or(variables.isMaster ,variables.isRelease)
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH%
          echo %ISMASTER%
          echo %ISRELEASE%
          echo %ISHOTFIX%
          echo %CHECKCONDITION%
      condition: or(variables.isMaster ,variables.isRelease)
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH%
          echo %ISMASTER%
          echo %ISRELEASE%
          echo %ISHOTFIX%
          echo %CHECKCONDITION%
```